# XRDP for multiple monitors (secure?)

Tags: server, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop, vnc, xrdp

I want to use Xrdp (VNC would be ok too, maybe?) to connect to a machine through a pretty crappy network. I have multiple monitors on my local, client side machine, and I need the remote session to allow dual monitor support. I know I can just stretch the window of the client to cover both monitors, but that solution is inadequate for the programs I'll be using. Is there a way to configure multiple monitor support? I know the windows RPD server/client supports multiple monitors, but does Xrdp?

On another note, a secure connection is of some concern, but not hyper critical. Network administrators have proposed using guac and xrdp for a secure RDP connection, but guac, as I understand, basically creates a remote desktop window in a browser and therefore does not support the dual monitor behavior I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I use TigerVNC server on Ubuntu and TigerVNC clinet on windows with 4 monitors of different sizes. I don't have any issues.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Current XRDP (xrdp/jammy - 0.9.17-2ubuntu2) supports multi-monitor without any special configuration.  I cannot speak to how well it works with Microsoft's RDP client as I have no Windows workstations with multiple monitors.  But I use Remmina 1.4.25 from my Jammy workstation (quad monitors) to access Ubuntu and Windows targets alike in multi-monitor mode.  Aside from a quirk here and there, Remmina works very well with both XRDP and Microsoft RDS.

One note on XRDP sessions: if the console on a Ubuntu/XRDP target is already in use, an inbound RDP session will not be successful until the console session logs out.

As to SSH tunneling your RDP sessions, tunnels would be initiate by the client and, again, I cannot speak to Microsoft clients but Remmina fully supports this.